# Restarting the Interval Timer?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

By `restarting` i mean reset it so that it will restart the time, so that it takes 3 seconds from the restart.

My code is:

```
/* ********** Forside Slider ********** */

var slider_current_id = 1;

$(".slidermenu").live("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    clearInterval(window.slider_timer);
    window.slider_timer = setInterval(start_slider_timer(), 3000);
    window.slider_current_id = parseInt(id, 10);
    $('.slidermenu.currentone').animate({backgroundColor: '#FCFBFB'}, 'slow');
    $('.slidermenu.currentone').removeClass("currentone");
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'}, 'slow');
    $(this).addClass("currentone");
    $('#activeimage img.currentone').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#activeimage img.currentone').removeClass("currentone");
    $('#activeimage img[data-id='+id+']').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#activeimage img[data-id='+id+']').addClass("currentone");
});

function start_slider_timer() {
    if (window.slider_current_id == 5) {
        window.slider_current_id = 1;
    }else{
        window.slider_current_id = window.slider_current_id + 1;
    }
    $('.slidermenu.currentone').animate({backgroundColor: '#FCFBFB'}, 'slow');
    $('.slidermenu.currentone').removeClass("currentone");
    $('.slidermenu[data-id='+window.slider_current_id+']').animate({backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'}, 'slow');
    $('.slidermenu[data-id='+window.slider_current_id+']').addClass("currentone");
    $('#activeimage img.currentone').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#activeimage img.currentone').removeClass("currentone");
    $('#activeimage img[data-id='+window.slider_current_id+']').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#activeimage img[data-id='+window.slider_current_id+']').addClass("currentone");
}

var slider_timer = setInterval(start_slider_timer(), 3000);
```

I dont get any errors, it just doesn't run.. It is my `Interval` which doesn't run at all.

Hope someone can help me solve this.

Comment: Do you mind providing us with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here http://jsbin.com/oqenan/1/

Comment: You should try also putting your code in [JSFiddle.net](http://JSFiddle.net/). They aso have a code fixer, so-to-speak, which can detect errors or problems in your code.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Bjpx/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22673/discussion-between-erik-hansen-and-dumb-search)

Comment: I somehow managed to make it work. I think it is because of @dystroy , but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis to provide the function as parameter instead of calling it. Replace

```
var slider_timer = setInterval(start_slider_timer(), 3000);
```

with

```
var slider_timer = setInterval(start_slider_timer, 3000);
```

Note that if you want to "restart" the timer, you first have to clear it with

```
clearInterval(slider_timer);
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced `var slider_timer = setInterval(start_slider_timer(), 3000);` with `var slider_timer = setInterval(start_slider_timer, 3000);`, and I allready have the `clearInterval(slider_timer);` on line 8. But without luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change to this

```
var slider_timer =  setInterval('start_slider_timer()', 1000);
```

_

Comment: *-1* Huh? Why? This doesn't make sense to me... The only change you made was cutting the time in more then half.

Comment: @DumbSearch the answer puts the function in quotation marks, which means it will work, though dystroy's solution is probably better.

Comment: Where should I put this then? Just without the `()`?

Comment: @ErikHansen The point of this answer is that you put the function inside quotation marks and retain the `()`. `setInterval` accepts *either* a string containing some code, *or* the name of a function, as its first argument. But if dystroy's answer doesn't work for you then I don't think this one will either.

Comment: Ok, this seems to make sense. I can only revert my downvote if you edit your answer. Do you mind making a very slight edit to your answer? So I can upvote?